# Linking error in minix system call that changes sched process' state

Tags: c, operating-system, minix

I need to change a sched process' state by creating and calling a system call. And that's my code for do_settickets system call.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "pm.h"
#include "../sched/sched.h"
#include "../sched/schedproc.h"
#include <assert.h>
#include <minix/com.h>
#include <machine/archtypes.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LOW_THRESHOLD 1
#define HIGH_THRESHOLD 30

int do_settickets(void){
        struct schedproc *rpm;
        int set_ticket = m_in.m1_i2; // get wanted set ticket value from message
        int index = m_in.m1_i1; //get processIndex
        rpm = &schedproc[index];
        if(set_ticket < LOW_THRESHOLD){
                rpm->ticket = LOW_THRESHOLD;
        }else if(set_ticket > HIGH_THRESHOLD){
                rpm->ticket = HIGH_THRESHOLD;
        }else{
                rpm->ticket = set_ticket;
        }
        return 1;
}
```

When i use "make hdboot" int /usr/src/releasetools, there is a linking error that say:

```
do_settickets.o: In function `do_settickets':
do_settickets.c:(.text+0x1a): undefined reference to `schedproc'
do_settickets.c:(.text+0x2d): undefined reference to `schedproc'
```

That's the header file that contains declaration for "struct schedproc"

```
  GNU nano 2.4.2                                       File: schedproc.h                                                                                      

/* This table has one slot per process.  It contains scheduling information
 * for each process.
 */
#include <limits.h>

#include <minix/bitmap.h>

/* EXTERN should be extern except in main.c, where we want to keep the struct */
#ifdef _MAIN
#undef EXTERN
#define EXTERN
#endif

#ifndef CONFIG_SMP
#define CONFIG_MAX_CPUS 1
#endif

/**
 * We might later want to add more information to this table, such as the
 * process owner, process group or cpumask.
 */

EXTERN struct schedproc {
        endpoint_t endpoint;    /* process endpoint id */
        endpoint_t parent;      /* parent endpoint id */
        unsigned flags;         /* flag bits */
        int ticket;
        int hasTorpil;
        /* User space scheduling */
        unsigned max_priority;  /* this process' highest allowed priority */
        unsigned priority;              /* the process' current priority */
        unsigned time_slice;            /* this process's time slice */
        unsigned cpu;           /* what CPU is the process running on */
        bitchunk_t cpu_mask[BITMAP_CHUNKS(CONFIG_MAX_CPUS)]; /* what CPUs is the
                                                                process allowed
                                                                to run on */
} schedproc[NR_PROCS];

/* Flag values */
#define IN_USE          0x00001 /* set when 'schedproc' slot in use */
```

What should i do to modify schedproc array in a systemcall?

Comment: Did you define _MAIN in your main program may be #define _MAIN

Comment: thank you so much you saved my hours.